# Docker - No matching manifest for linux/arm64/v8 in the manifest list entries - Ubuntu 22.04/arm64/v8

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, arm64, ubuntu-22.04

I have installed Docker and docker compose and tested it and i got the “Hello World” message, so everything works fine

After that i tried to install a Node.js backend, but idk why i keep getting this error message

> " no matching manifest for linux/arm64/v8 in the manifest list entries
> "

i have a VPS server, 4 CPU, 24 RAM, running Ubuntu 22.04, ARM64
Idk what is the problem and what shall i do to fix it!

Someone in the docker community said:

> That image does not have a compatible version with your CPU. You can
> try to use QEMU to emulate it.
>
> https://www.stereolabs.com/docs/docker/building-arm-container-on-x86/

```
sudo apt-get install qemu binfmt-support qemu-user-static
docker run --platform linux/amd64 ...
```

> This way you can use the AMD64 version, but the emulation is not
> always perfect, and it may be slower then running a container from a
> compatible image.

I installed the qemu, but still don't know what shall i do to fix the no matching manifest issue!

note: i'm not familiar with docker stuff, just trying to install the Node.js backend website because it's requiring docker.

I hope if someone can help, Thanks!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Ok .. here is the solution

open your docker-compose.yml, if you're using nano then

```
nano docker-compose.yml
```

Now add the following:

```
platform: linux/amd64
```

for each MyService

Example:

```
services:
   myservice:
      platform: linux/amd64
   myotherservice:
      platform: linux/amd64
```

then you can run:

```
docker compose up -d
```

This works 100% for me, and big thanks to [Ákos Takács](https://forums.docker.com/u/rimelek/summary) for his help.

Comment: Hi, feel free to mark your own answer as answer.

Comment: Additionally: do you know what is causing this?

Comment: I would believe that you are on a new MacBook with M1 or M2 processors indicated by the /v8. Just forcing a specific linux plattform might have some other problems. Be sure to always select Apple Chip when installing Docker Desktop (or any other software you might require) and do not use the Intel Chip version. Wont always fix things but in many places this could help.

Comment: The microservice infrastructure we are working with is run by people on Linux PCs, Linux servers, Windows and Mac. The above bug happens only for Mac. I can't easily test on everyone's computer, but wouldn't hardcoding the platform break the other instances?